# Snappy file compression adds counter values to the data

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, compression

> On compressing a file using snappy compression through map reduce ,it adds counter values to the data .What should be done to remove counters while compression.
>   Below is some part of code :

```
 JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(conf,SnappyCompression.class);
 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(jobConf, new Path(arg[0]));
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf, new Path(arg[1]));
 FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(jobConf, true);
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(jobConf, SnappyCodec.class);
```

And  Is there any command to compress file in snappy through Unix??

Comment: Got solution for one of the question I asked.

Comment: Is there any command in Unix tocompress file in snappy.I have command for bzip.

Answer (score 0):

The only tool I'm aware of to decompress raw snappy data is the CLI in [Squash](https://quixdb.github.io/squash/) (which I wrote).

If you want to compress/decompress to one of the various available framing formats available, [snzip](https://github.com/kubo/snzip) should do the trick.  It doesn't handle raw snappy data, but it does support the official framing format as well as a few others.

AFAIK neither tool has been packaged for any distributions yet.